# Python/Scikit-learn - Linear Regression - Access to Linear Regression Equation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I've built a few different linear regressions, using the same group of predictor variables, as you can see below:

```
model=LinearRegression()
model.fit(X=predictor_train,y=target_train)
prediction_train=model.predict(predictor_train)
pred=model.predict(main_frame.iloc[-1:,1:])
```

To create the predictions of the target variable, I suppose that the Scikit algorithm created an equation with those "predictor variables". My question is: How do I access that equation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `params = model.coef_`. This returns an array with the weight of each model input.

Note that this is a linear equation, so to get the prediction for yourself, you want to form an equation such that your prediction, `y = sum([input[i] * params[i]])`, if you had some input array called `input`. This is the dot product, if you're familiar with linear algebra between the parameter vector and the feature vector.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from math import fabs
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def get_regression_formula(df, independent_vars, dependent_var):
    X = df[independent_vars]
    y = df[dependent_var]
    regression = LinearRegression()
    regression.fit(X, y)
    formula = [f"{regression.intercept_:.2f} "]
    for i, var in enumerate(independent_vars):
        coef = regression.coef_[i]
        coef_abs = fabs(coef)
        if coef_abs < 0.1:
            continue
        formula.append(f"{'+' if coef > 0 else '-'} {coef_abs:.2f} * {var} ")
    return f"{dependent_var} = {''.join(formula)}"
```

Usage example:

```py
>>> df.columns
Index(['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'y'], dtype='object')
>>> print(get_regression_formula(df, ["x1", "x2", "x3"], "y")
```

Comment: How to pass the dataframe columns? 
Tried many ways, got error,     

result = get_regression_formula(df, 'Year', 'AMBALA'),    

or

result = get_regression_formula(df, df['col1'], df['col2']),   

print (result)

Comment: @AbhilashSinghChauhan added usage example